# two shooters, probabilities that have a possibility of going to infinity

Tags: probability

I've been struggling with some probabilities that have a possibility of going to infinity and i would like some advises for solving them an example would be:

"two shooters, who can hit the target with probability of 0.47 and 0.83 shoot at the target until they hit it. what is the probability the first shooter will need less bullets than the second? "

I am more interested in solutions instead of answers as i want to learn how to solve these, but any input will be appreciated

Comment: Do you know about conditional probability?

Comment: yes i do, but this is not quite the same as both probabilities have a chance of going to infinity and both of these are independent as both of them will shoot until they hit the target, not until one of them hits it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these "infinite" possibilities can be handled by a recursion.  For example , if you define "success" as the first shooter taking strictly less bullets than the second, you can list the 4 possibilities on the first shot:
a) they both hit, which is not a success
b) shooter 1 hits/shooter 2 misses, which is a success whose probability you can calculate easily
c) shooter 1 missed/shooter 2 hits, which is not a success
d) they both miss, which is an event whose probability you can calculate, but this leaves the game back where it started, so the probability of success after this event d) is the same as it was before.

You should be able to build an equation from this which can be easily solved.